# ABS prints consistently splitting in the same place

Tags: print-quality, filament, ultimaker-cura, octoprint, layer-height

I am printing ABS in an enclosure and most of the prints have worked out well with minor tweaking. However, the top layer always seems to split or skip a step (not sure which).

[image: Split top layer]

[image: Layer was peeled of on previous prints]

The cube is sliced in Ultimaker Cura 4.3.0 with 0.2 mm layer height, 0.4 mm nozzle, 80 °C bed on lexan and a 235 °C hotend.

The G-code to the calibration cube/chep's calibration cube is attached: [`PI3XL_CHEPCalibrationCube.gcode`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GekxfKeUgv337_r0DeJ6_2JTWV_fT1_R/view?usp=sharing).

While I'm on the subject of slicing and calibration my calibration angle is coming out as before in Simplify3D, this time the layers look great but the onion skinning within the print itself so I could actually separate the calibration angle like an onion.

Comment: Can you test with the cubes scaled up and down by 10% to verify it's the top layer rather than layers at a certain Z-axis position?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I have dealt with this problem myself! I messed around with the slicer a little bit, and I found that if you make the print layer height 0.15 or 0.10 mm, it will be better. The image you attached looks as though the printer was splitting a step and only printing that part. I can't think of a reason why it would do that. I also can't find anything online, so I would just play with the print settings or change the layer height until it comes out how you want it.

Comment: It is generally known/accepted that thicker layers provide better adhesion than thinner layers because of the heat capacity of the filament being laid down.

Comment: @0scar that aspect of 3D printing is less investigated than it could be: are we talking at given printing speed, or at given flowrate? in the latter case, thicker layers increase the layer time, compensating pretty much the increased heat capacity (not completely, but almost).

Comment: @FarO That are good questions, a separate question (if not already out there) might be good to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Since it happens in the same place each time, it's either G-code or mechanical. I've seen things like this happen with dirty gantries, or a dirty Z-axis guide.

If it's not mechanical, there may be something in the G-code that causes it, such as too many retractions in one area, or similar.